# Need to stop downloading DocuSign envelopes multiple times

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am using these examples:

- [DocuSign API Walkthrough 06 in C# - Download Envelope Document(s)](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/getEnvelopeDocuments)
- [DocuSign API Walkthrough 02 in C# - Get Envelope Info of a specified envelope](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/getEnvelopeInformation#csharp)

After reviewing the information returned by the "Get Envelope Info" code I don't see a property like `<lastdownload>` or something similar...

Is there someplace within Docusign that tracks if a envelope has been downloaded or not so I can programmatically ignore anything already downloaded?  I would prefer to avoid using `<status>` completed and `<statusChangedDateTime>` with date ranges as the key to determine what to pull as some of the completed envelopes have already been manually downloaded and processed.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially your looking for a flag from DocuSign to signify if there has been previously a request, or GET, for document x.  Whether it was successfully downloaded or not would not be known to DocuSign. The short if it is no, this flag doesn't exist. This would be a flag that you keep inside of your own application to determine if the file is available locally.

Additionally you can have a look at DocuSign Connect services. Where DocuSign can automatically push information to you as it becomes available and relevant.
https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSign_Connect_Service_Guide.pdf